# How do I validate specific fields in a ASP.NET Dynamic Data Site?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio, dynamic-data

I have built a dynamic data asp.net site and I have scaffolding on. I want to be able to validate specific fields using specific regular expressions when the rows in grid view are in edit mode. I cannot seem to find up to date documentation from Microsoft on how to do this. Where can I go to find out how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use client side or server side (remote) validation with JQuery validation plugin.
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation. You can do it for dynamically added elements and for individual elements in the form too.

Here are some examples 
http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/06/jquery-validation-with-asp-net/
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-validation-with-asp-net-webforms/